# Can jmeter create requests using wsdl as soapui

Tags: jmeter, soapui, jmeter-plugins

Can jmeter create requests using wsdl as soapui?

When you open wsdl in soapui it create all the request available

Do I have such/similar option to do it using jmeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Itself JMeter cannot, however you can record SoapUI execution through JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

SoapUI proxy configuration lives under File -> Preferences -> Proxy Settings

[image: SoapUI Proxy Configuration]

Another option is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool to convert SoapUI XML project into JMeter .jmx test script, see [SoapUI Support](http://gettaurus.org/docs/SoapUI/) and [How to Convert SoapUI xml to JMeter jmx](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-soapui-xml-jmeter-jmx) articles for more details.

Comment: why taurus create and open jmeter per request? also why is it configure by default to loop forever?

Comment: @Dmitri-t: Is it possible to convert it from JMeter to SoapUI?