# WSDL file import in JMeter 3

Tags: soap, jmeter, wsdl

I try to execute `SOAP` requests in `JMeter`, but I can't find possibility to import `WSDL` files. I found, that it was present as `SOAP/XML-RPC Request` in `JMeter 2.X` with an URL field, but it is deprecated in `JMeter 3.X`. There is no such field in current `HTTP Request Sampler`.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207285/can-jmeter-create-requests-using-wsdl-as-soapui

Comment: @user7294900 : Is it possible to convert it from JMeter to SoapUI?

Comment: You want to convert jmeter script to be used soapui?

Comment: @user7294900 : Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP/XML-RPC Request was removed for performance reasons.

There is now a Template called Building a SOAP Webservice Test Plan that shows how to test SOAP WS:

[image: SOAP Template]

When you need to create a test from a WSDL, you should use SOAP UI and then convert your SOAP WS Test to JMeter through the following procedure:

- Start JMeter , select Template Recording , go to HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder and start it
- Start SOAP UI and configure JMeter as a proxy in Soap UI
- Run your Soap UI Webservice
- It will appear in JMeter, you can then variabilize what you want in JMeter and run your test

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to convert from JMeter project to SoapUI too?

Comment: Some functions, like dataHandler, file attachments are not yet supported by JMeter.